# for loop eats every second output

Tags: java

i ve got an Problem with my for loop.
if i dont use a for loop i get the right results back.
The output method is 
sortPriosAtPeriodAtRessource() and works fine if my code is static;
However i cant make it a static code because sortPriosAtPeriodAtRessource sometimes will end at (3,4) for example and sometimes at (9,8)

So with a for loop like in my second code he never shows for (1,1) and (3,1). He always "eats" the second output. I think he doesnt even access it but i seem to be blind to find the mistake in my loop.

**Works:**

```
    PriosSort = datafile.sortPriosAtPeriodAtRessource(0,1);
    System.out.println("");
    for(ProductRessource m : PriosSort){

        System.out.println("Key: " + m.getKey() + " für Makroperiode: " + 1 + " Prio: " + m.getPrioAtPeriode(j));
    }
    PriosSort = datafile.sortPriosAtPeriodAtRessource(1,1);
    System.out.println("");
    for(ProductRessource m : PriosSort){

        System.out.println("Key: " + m.getKey() + " für Makroperiode: " + 2 + " Prio: " + m.getPrioAtPeriode(j));
    }

    PriosSort = datafile.sortPriosAtPeriodAtRessource(2,1);
    System.out.println("");
    for(ProductRessource m : PriosSort){

        System.out.println("Key: " + m.getKey() + " für Makroperiode: " + 3 + " Prio: " + m.getPrioAtPeriode(j));
    }

    PriosSort = datafile.sortPriosAtPeriodAtRessource(3,1);
    System.out.println("");
    for(ProductRessource m : PriosSort){

        System.out.println("Key: " + m.getKey() + " für Makroperiode: " + 4 + " Prio: " + m.getPrioAtPeriode(j));
    }
```

**Doensnt Work:**

datafile.getAnzahlRessources could be 1,
makroperiodencount could be 4

```
 for(int i = 1;  i <= datafile.getAnzahlRessources(); i++){

        for(int j = 0 ; j < makroperiodencount; j++){

            PriosSort = datafile.sortPriosAtPeriodAtRessource(j,i);
            System.out.println("");
            for(ProductRessource m : PriosSort){
                periode = j + 1;
                System.out.println("Key: " + m.getKey() + " für Makroperiode: " + periode + " Prio: " + m.getPrioAtPeriode(j));
            }               
            j++;
        }

    i++;
        }
```

Comment: You double every x++ that's why.. Remove the increments that are "alone" on a line

Comment: You increment j two times: one time in the condition and one time at the end of the block. Remove the last increment and it should work.

Comment: gosh......... iam so stupid :))) Shouldnt be coding anymore today i guess.Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the extra i++ and j++ and try this:

```
 for(int i = 1;  i <= datafile.getAnzahlRessources(); i++){

        for(int j = 0 ; j < makroperiodencount; j++){

            PriosSort = datafile.sortPriosAtPeriodAtRessource(j,i);
            System.out.println("");
            for(ProductRessource m : PriosSort){
                periode = j + 1;
                System.out.println("Key: " + m.getKey() + " für Makroperiode: " + periode + " Prio: " + m.getPrioAtPeriode(j));
            }               
        }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you double inc i and j

```
for(int i = 1;  i <= datafile.getAnzahlRessources(); i++){

    for(int j = 0 ; j < makroperiodencount; j++){

        PriosSort = datafile.sortPriosAtPeriodAtRessource(j,i);
        System.out.println("");
        for(ProductRessource m : PriosSort){
            periode = j + 1;
            System.out.println("Key: " + m.getKey() + " für Makroperiode: " + periode + " Prio: " + m.getPrioAtPeriode(j));
        }               

    }
    }
```